# Fastest algorithm to solve quantile regression with single predictor and no intercept

Tags: r, quantile-regression, coordinate-descent

I was wondering what would be the most efficient algorithm to solve [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) with a single predictor and no intercept? 
I tried a Brent line search, but unfortunately that's no faster than the interior point method implemented in `quantreg` (see below). So I was wondering if there would be potentially faster ways to do a quantreg model with a single predictor? Ideally I would also like to be able to use warm starts, which would exclude interior point methods...

EDIT: In this paper, ["cqrReg: An R Package for Quantile and Composite Quantile Regression and Variable Selection"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.04126), on page 14 I see a coordinate descent algorithm mentioned to solve quantile regression (implemented in R in https://github.com/cran/cqrReg/blob/master/R/QR.cd.R and https://github.com/cran/cqrReg/blob/master/src/QRCD.cpp; `qrfit(x, y, tau, beta0, method="cd")`). This might fit the bill, except that the current implementation always fits an intercept, which I don't want. Would anyone know if that algorithm could be adapted to also allow models to be fit without intercept, and what changes in the Rcpp code this would entail?

```
set.seed(1)
n=500
p=1
a=rnorm(n*p, mean = 10, sd = 1)
x=matrix(a,n,p)
beta=rnorm(p,1,1)
beta=matrix(beta,p,1)
y=x%*%beta-matrix(rnorm(n,0.1,1),n,1)
tau=0.01 # example tau, here to get underapproximation

library(microbenchmark)

# quantreg solution
library(quantreg)
microbenchmark(microbenchmark(rq.fit.br(x, y, tau = tau)$coefficients)) # quantreg, 149 µs, beta=0.84

# using Brent line search, using [0, least square estimate] search interval
# function giving log(quantile loss)
logquantloss = function(beta, x, y, tau) { r=y-beta*x   
                                           log(sum(r*(r>0) - (1-tau)*r)) } 
microbenchmark(optimize(logquantloss, 
                       interval=c(0, mean(x*y)/mean(x*x)), # least square beta = maximum
                       x=x, y=y, tau=tau)$minimum) # 184 µs, beta=0.84
```

Comment: When all regressors are positive, clearly the solution is given by a suitable quantile of the $y_i/x_i,$ which is found with $O(n)$ effort. The generalization to data that straddle zero shouldn't be much harder.

Comment: Ha yes of course - stupid that I hadn't thought of that... microbenchmark(quantile(y/x,tau)) runs in 139 µs and indeed gives 0.844 in my example... Next question then would be if you would happen to know of the fastest Rcpp quantile() implementation in R that runs in O(n) time?

Comment: I don't--but it's easy to code yourself.  Emulate a Quicksort algorithm or use a heap.

Comment: Thanks - this Rcpp quantile function here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26786078/rcpp-quantile-implementation, is already 4x faster than quantile() but will keep on looking. Quicksort is only O(n log n) efficient though isn't it, not O(n)?

Comment: You are correct about Quicksort: but when you are targeting a single quantile, rather than sorting the entire array, the expected time is $O(n).$  The implicit multiplier is a little smaller, too.

Comment: So the algo you mean is quickselect, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect Or some of the algos mentioned here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm ?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers - found what I need here: http://yiqun-dai.blogspot.com/2017/03/rcpp-example-partition-based-selection.html and that runs in 6 µs as opposed to 139 µs for my example :-) Great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran across this and thought I should try to clarify a couple of points.  It it true that the the quantile regression solution to this "regression through the origin" problem is a quantile of the y_i/x_i values, but it is a weighted quantile with weights |x_i|.  Floyd and Rivest's SELECT is somewhat quicker than Hoare's quickselect for ordinary sample quantiles, but an efficient adaptation for weighted quantiles is to my knowledge still open. I've written a note about this here:
[http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/~roger/research/vinaigrettes/kuantile.pdf](http://www.econ.uiuc.edu/%7Eroger/research/vinaigrettes/kuantile.pdf)

Comment: Many thanks for that! So if I get you right the solution of a zero-intercept quantile regression is a weighted quantile y_i/x_i with weights abs(x_i), right? Would this function https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/robsurvey/html/weighted_quantile.html be a reasonably efficient implementation for that (it's using quickselect)? I was also wondering what the solution would be of a univariate zero intercept weighted quantile regression with weights w_i? The weighted quantile of y_i/x_i with weights abs(x_i*w_i) or something like that? Any thoughts or references/pointers?